# How to "pluck" an image field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My Model "**Appimage**" has the following fields

```
AppImage(id: integer, content: text, app_image_file_name: string, app_image_content_type: string, app_image_file_size: integer, app_image_updated_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Consider it has five records. Now, I want to fetch all the values of **app_image** field (*in url format*) like we do `ModelName.pluck(:some_field_name)`.

If I fetch an URL for the first record `AppImage.first.app_image.url`, it returns as follows

```
http://s3-amazonaws.com/my_app/attachments/3/original/file_name.jpg?1446218644
```

Please help me if you have idea about it.

Comment: Are you using carrierwave for this?

Comment: Am using paperclip..

Comment: Well, if urls are not stored as a field, then `pluck` is not applicable. Best you can do is fetch partially filled records and `map` them to urls.